# Adding item in Sortable Grid Behavior

Tags: php, yii2

I use Sortable Grid Behavior and when I try to add item i have problem with my sort attribute "The SQL being executed was: SELECT MAX"

```
 public function behaviors()
{
    return [
      'sort' => [
        'class' => SortableGridBehavior::class,
        'sortableAttribute' => 'sort'
      ],
   ];
}
```

my action in controller

```
public function actionAddLibraryValue($libId)
{
    $request = Yii::$app->request;
    $model = new LibrariesValues();
    $model->lib_id = $libId;

    if ($request->isPjax && $request->isPost && $model->load($request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
        try {
            $model->save();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            print_r($e);exit;
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is a problem in widget, I redefined class method and now it's work

```
 class CustomSortableGrid extends SortableGridBehavior
 {
    public function beforeInsert()
    {
    /** @var ActiveRecord $model */
    $model = $this->owner;
    if (!$model->hasAttribute($this->sortableAttribute)) {
        throw new InvalidConfigException("Invalid sortable attribute `{$this->sortableAttribute}`.");
    }

    $query = $model::find();
    if (is_callable($this->scope)) {
        call_user_func($this->scope, $query);
    }

    /* Override model alias if defined in the model's class */
    $query->from([$model::tableName()]);

    $maxOrder = $query->max('{{' . trim($model::tableName(), '{}') . '}}.[[' . $this->sortableAttribute . ']]');
    $model->{$this->sortableAttribute} = $maxOrder + 1;
}
}
```